# Show there exists at least one $c\in [0,1]$ such that $|f(c)|=1$ .

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

Let $T=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|=1\} $ and $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be continuous such that $f(0)=0, f(1)=2$ . Show that there exists at least $c\in [0,1]$ such that $f(c)\in T$ .

My work: Let $h(x)=|f(x)|-1$  . Then $h(0)=-1 $ and $h(1)=1 $ .As $h$ is real-valued by IVT , there is $c\in [0,1]$ such that $h(c)=0$ . Hence $|f(c)|=1$ . Proved .

Is my proof correct ? I'm little confuse about domain and co-domain here . Please provide alternative solution if you have . Thank you .

Comment: You have to assert that $h$ is real-valued and continuous, but otherwise that's fine. It is continous  because the function $|\cdot|:\mathbb C\to\mathbb R$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the map $\Gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow R$. where $\Gamma(x)=|f(x)|$. $\Gamma$ is continuous since it is a composition of two continuous functions. $\Gamma(0)=1 $ and $\Gamma(1)=2$ hence by Intermediate Value Property of continuous real valued functions on a connected space we have $\exists c\in[0,1]$ such that $\Gamma(c)=1$ which was to be proved.

Comment: This was too easy